# Strange Ethconsole Output for getbalance typo

Tags: web3js

I came across this when I made a typo checking my ETH balance from the ethconsole. I had incorrectly typed `web3.eth.coinbase`. I poked around and anything after `web3.eth.` that is a typo brought up a balance of 7088.445913801793117574.

I asked on Redit with the example of `web3.eth.wololo` and Nick Johnson posted to following response:

> `web3.eth.wololo` evaluates to `undefined`, and `web3.eth.getBalance`
>   apparently treats `undefined` the same as `0` - so you're seeing the
>   balance of account `0`.

So, back to the console.  I have only 1 account and this is account 0.  I will post my outputs below:

```
c:\>geth --cache=1204 -rpc --datadir "f:\Ethereum" account list
```

> **Account #0: {dd289578d8915156de085df3d03062335238a293}** f:\Ethereum\keystore\UTC--2016-06-21T17-26-40.480551500Z--dd289578d8915156de085df3d03062335238a293

```
c:\>geth --cache=1204 -rpc --datadir "f:\Ethereum" --unlock 0xDD289578D8915156De085DF3d03062335238a293
```

!! Truncated !!

> **Unlocking account 0xDD289578D8915156De085DF3d03062335238a293** | Attempt 1/3
>   Passphrase:
>
> I1010 00:30:37.012616 cmd/geth/accountcmd.go:189] **Unlocked account dd289578d8915156de085df3d03062335238a293**

!!! Eth Console !!!

```
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.wololo), "ether")
```

> 7088.445913801793117574

```
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.coinbase), "ether")
```

> 15.9387038629625851

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: web3.eth.wololo, to: '0xDD289578D8915156De085DF3d03062335238a293', value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"), gas:22000});
```

> (shell):4334: Error: account is locked
>   
>         throw errors.InvalidResponse(result);
>   
>                      ^
>   
> Error: account is locked
>   
>     at Object.module.exports.InvalidResponse ((shell):2103:16)
>   
>     at RequestManager.send ((shell):4334:22)
>   
>     at Method.send ((shell):4002:59)
>   
>     at (shell):1:10
>   
> Error: Uncaught Error: account is locked

Comment: You can see the account here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000. The balance is largely from people accidentally sending money there in the very early days before clients properly validated addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Nick was talking about account 0, he did not mean `web3.eth.accounts[0]`, he meant account `"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`.

```
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"))
7088.445913801793117574
```